# "They are blindly optimistic to say the season is over."

Tags: sentence-construction

> They are blindly optimistic to say the season is over.

This is a line I am writing. I am trying to say

> It is blindly optimistic of them to say the season is over.

Do the two sentences mean the same thing? I vaguely recall there is the structure "*subject* + *be* + *adjective* + *to do something*" that means the *subject* takes an action because they can be described as *adjective*. But I can't remember what the structure is called; nor am I able to find any explanation on the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

I think the sentence is acceptable, but I would prefer:

> They are blindly optimistic in saying the season is over.

The use of two present tense verbs, 'are' and 'saying', helps clarify the cause and effect nature of the statement you want to make.